# Find largest value from two lists, check it against its counterpart in the other list, assign it, then do same for 2nd largest value, etc

Tags: python-3.x, list, max

I have two lists:

```
a = [3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to find the maximum value across both lists, and compare it to its counterpart (same index) in the *other* list. If for example the max value is in list a and its counterpart in list b is smaller, I need to allocate the max value's index to that list's masterlist:

```
a_master = []
b_master = []
```

If its counterpart is equal to the max value, do nothing and repeat the process for the next biggest value, but ignore the index that has already been allocated to a master list.
So in this example, the initial max value is 3, and a[0] > b[0] means that we append index 0 to the a_master list. Next, we see that b[2] > a[2] therefore we append index 2 to the b_master list. a[3] = b[3] so we don't allocate anything.

Now repeat the process for the next biggest value: 2. a[2] = 2 but index 2 has already been allocated and thus should be ignored. b[0] = 2 but has also already been allocated. b[1] = 2 > a[1] thus index 1 gets allocated to b_master.

Since all remaining values are equal to their counterparts, we're done and the resulting master lists are:

```
a_master = [0]
b_master = [2, 1]
```

Kudos for the most pythonian answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about sorting `a` beforehand into tupled pairs of `(index, element)`, and comparing it with the second list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

sorted_a = sorted(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
# [(0, 3), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 0), (10, 0)]

a_master = []
b_master = []
for i, x in sorted_a:
    if x > b[i]:
        a_master.append(i)
    elif x < b[i]:
        b_master.append(i)

print(a_master)
print(b_master)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[0]
[2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, works for me. It formed the core of my problem which I was now able to expand.